# (jQuery, RegEx) Remove from the beginning to some word

Tags: jquery, regex, dom, replace

### Need a simple RegEx for text replacement: from the beginning to the only known word.

**Before:**

> *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur **adipisicing** elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.*

**After:**

> *elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.*

The only static word is **adipisicing** so everything else is variable.

I've used this RegEx:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/^[^adipisicing]*(adipisicing)/,''));
```

Works fine.. but I'm sure there is a shorter way!

Comment: That regex doesn't match anything in the example text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kh7aD/

since indexOf is already in one of the post try using split.

Hope this will help you!

**code**

```
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";


str = str.split('adipisicing')[1];
```

​

Comment: That's good, but what if a word doesn't exist? I'd add the check or `||`. Another thing, is what if there are two words? :)

Answer (score 0):

use this  regex `^.*adipisicing`

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
var tmphtml = $(this).html();
var word = "adipisicing";
$(this).html( tmphtml.substr(tmphtml.indexOf(word)+word.length) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expressions:

```
var word = "adipisicing";

$(this).html(function(i, val) {
    return val.substring(val.indexOf(word) + word.length);
});
```

---

Using regular expression:

```
$(this).html(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/^.*\badipisicing\b/, "");
});
```

Here `\b` will bound a word but not a set of characters.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rVuh7/

Comment: @Engineer Yep, I also had this option in mind first of all :)